# Filtering nested data in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to filter the results by adding some conditions to where clause. But when I run my query, I still see results that don't match with my where condition

Code below still shows the values like map, click, list etc.

where NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, r"value1|value2|value3|value4")

```
hits.eventInfo.eventAction as event_action,
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel as event_label,
hits.eventInfo.eventValue as event_value,
count(*) as count
FROM
tablename, UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE
PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX)  BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
AND
hits.type = 'EVENT'
AND
NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, 
r"map|click|list|swipe")
GROUP BY
```

I expect the results without regex values but I can see them in resultset

Comment: Your values look like event actions but you're regex'ing on eventCategory - is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is GA data, you should be able to find an exhaustive list of all events you want to filter.

To be able to maintain it, and handle pretty large volume, you could create a temp or perma table (up to your build/run state) where you store your banned events values.

Then you left join with event value as join key(up to you, left==> GA Data, right==>Event Mask), specifying right key as null in where statement.

Correct me if i misunderstood your issue :)